# FIFO queue (or stack) implemented on disk, not ram (preferably in C++)

Tags: c++, c, queue, disk

Basically what I'm after is the equivalent of the Standard Template Library queue implemented in such a way as to use the disk for storage. The volume of data that will need to be in the queue is far greater than can be stored in the ram of most computers today.

Ideally, I'm after a library to use. However, any recommendation on how to implement this queue would be useful.

Comment: Often you can solve this by having a in-memory stack of handles.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to look at the [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/):

"The core of STXXL is an implementation of the C++ standard template library STL for external memory (out-of-core) computations, i.e., STXXL implements containers and algorithms that can process huge volumes of data that only fit on disks."

Comment: +1 Nice little library. I didn't know this existed!

Comment: It's a nice library.  It also supports striping data across multiple disks.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the [STLXX](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) library.  It contains a disk-based priority queue using the "[Sequence Heap](http://citeseerx.ksu.edu.sa/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.16.3589)" model described by Peter Sanders.

Answer (score 1):

A wild idea: Implement an allocator class that reads/writes to and from a file on disk and pass it to STL `deque` or `queue` or whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Cool idea, except that the typical STL container implementation allocator is only invoked to allocate/free memory. During ordinary iteration, for example, the allocator is not involved at all. And the container itself will not generate "page faults" to trigger page loads.

Comment: Boost::interprocess does exactly this. If you are in userspace with Boost, you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us about the data. Is each item large or small? Is it a fixed size or highly variable? The problem with disk storage is that as the items become more varied in size the more the problem begins to resemble a database problem. In which case you should probably look into something like a sqllite database as the backing store to your queue. Then you can just use SQL to pull the first record out.

If the data is really large you could just store each object on the filesystem using ever incrementing filename. Then you don't even need to store the queue in memory. The file date becomes your FIFO order. Just grab the oldest file in the directory to pull the first item off the "stack".

Finally if the data is small and numerous, you might consider overriding the Allocator of a std::list or std::deque. It might be possible to hide the file IO in the Allocator class. I don't have simple solution for the small and numerous data instance.

Answer (score 0):

this is how a creator of the queue handler will go of course there are constructors to code

```
if(p[i].printerq.size()>0)
                {
                    temp_int=p[i].printerq.back().getPid();
                    counter=0;
                    cout<<"Ready to continue?"<<endl;
                    system("pause");
                    system("cls");
                    cout<<"Printer "<<i+1<<endl<<endl;
                    do
                    {
                        if(counter==3)
                        {
                            cout<<"Ready to continue?"<<endl;
                            system("pause");
                            system("cls");
                            counter=0;
                        }
                        cout<<p[i].printerq.front();
                        p[i].printerq.push(p[i].printerq.front());
                        p[i].printerq.pop();
                        ++counter;
                    }while(temp_int!=p[i].printerq.front().getPid());
                    if(p[i].printerq.size()>1)
                    {
                        cout<<p[i].printerq.front();
                        p[i].printerq.push(p[i].printerq.front());
                        p[i].printerq.pop();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"Printer "<<i+1<<" is empty."<<endl;
                }
```